# make an activivity count down for 3 seconds and start another activity automatically

Tags: android

i am designing a app for some quiz.
i need an activity that starts when i press the start button waits for 1 sec displays a red image,watis for 1 sec again displays a yellow face and waits for another sec and displays a green image.

The activity that starts when start quiz is pressed.

> public class pgtwo extends Activity {

```
ImageView rface,yface,gface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.newpg2);            


    rface = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    yface = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    gface = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    rface.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    yface.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
    gface.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);



           Thread trd = new Thread(){           
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                sleep(1000);
                rface.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                sleep(1000);
                yface.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                sleep(1000);
                gface.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }finally{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.ak.qmttpack.pgthree");
                myIntent.putExtra("pname", pname);
                myIntent.putExtra("tabList", tabList);
                myIntent.putExtra("order",order);
                myIntent.putExtra("noq", noq);
                myIntent.putExtra("seq", seq);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        }
    };
    trd.start();


}
```

}

i set the images visability as invisable and after waiting for 1 second each image visability becomes visable.
it waits for few seconds and starts the next activity.it dosent work as expected to. why any help plese.
or is there another way to get what i need.

Comment: Could you please tell us what is not working?

Comment: the images are not visable at all.

Comment: the images are supposed to be displayed one after the other.but nothing is being diaplayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify the `UI` from your thread, and you are getting an `Exception` that you just ignore (which is very bad practice). To modify the `UI` from another thread you should either create a `Handler` inside the `onCreate()` method and then :

```
  handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                  rface.setVisibility(View.Visible);        
        }
    });
```

or use [`runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from you thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the visibility of your images by using runOnUIThread() method like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        rface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```